# How to Override Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::requestShippingRates Method

Tags: overrides

In my attempt to fetching shipping rates, I want to override/rewrite this core file `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address` to put my custom code. So that, I can call the original method using PHP's `parent::` construct.

However, I found the `Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request` object is created and used locally in the method `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::requestShippingRates`, hence I confused how to override/rewrite it.

```
public function requestShippingRates(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $item = null)
{
    /** @var $request Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request */
    $request = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_request');
    $request->setAllItems($item ? array($item) : $this->getAllItems());
    $request->setDestCountryId($this->getCountryId());
    $request->setDestRegionId($this->getRegionId());
    $request->setDestRegionCode($this->getRegionCode());

    /** My custom code shall added in my override class */
    $request->setDestCityId($this->getCityId());
    $request->setDestDistrictId($this->getDistrictId());
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to overwrite `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address`, you need to add this code in your `config.xml` file

File : `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<global>
       <models>
          <sales>
              <rewrite>
                  <quote_address>Namespace_Module_Model_Quote_Address</quote_address>
              </rewrite>
          </sales>
       </models>
</global>
```

If you use this code inside config.xml, that means instead of `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address`, your model class will be used by magento. If your custom model definition do not holds the requested method from default model, then magento is brave enough to use that method from original class.

Your model definition should look like this.

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Quote_Address extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address {

    public function requestShippingRates(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $item = null)
    {
       //ofcourse you can use here `Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_request')` if you need

       //no problems with that. 

       //this method will use by magento if `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::requestShippingRates` get requested
    }
}
```

So there is no doubt. You can rewrite this  class and alter how `requestShippingRates()` method works right now. You can invoke `Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request` class inside this function and still use it in your custom class

Comment: I wish to call the original method using parent:: construct in my rewrite model. So would be something like:
`public function requestShippingRates(...) {
   // add my own code
   parent::requestShippingRates();
}`