# Add data to Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods

I need to add a value to `Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request` depending on user selection.

To be more detailed: the frontend shows a checkbox depending on the selection (or not) of the checkbox my shipping model (extends `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate`) should recalculate different rates in the overloaded `public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)`.

**Question.**

- Where can i inject the value of the user input from?
- Which class should i overwrite/observe?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Store the user data as a quote/order custom option.

As an example:

http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-product-option-and-its-use-case-in-magento/

where the customer can choose the Delivery Date.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can add your value to the request in `requestShippingRates` method in `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address` model. File path to the model is `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php`. You should override this model and in the `requestShippingRates` method add something like this:

```
$request->setMyValue($this->getMyValue());
```

To override use [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31990/how-to-override-mage-sales-model-quote-addressrequestshippingrates-method#answer-31995) on magento stackexchange.